Polars lazyframe not returning specified schema order after collecting
I have a function which runs in a loop performing calculations on a list of arrays.
At a point during the first iteration of the function, a polars lazyframe is initialised.
On the following iterations, a new dataframe is specified using the same schema, and the two dataframes are joined row-wise using pl.vstack, and then specified as a lazyframe again.

import numpy as np
import polars as pl



def my_func():

  array_list = [np.zeros((1,19))]*2 #this is just for example and not representative of shape of real array.


  for i, _ in enumerate(array_list):

      #calculations are done here


      result = np.zeros((1,19)) #result of calculations (correct shape of real result)

      if i < 1:
          result_df = pl.DataFrame(data = result,
                       schema = {
                              'MDL',
                              'MVL',
                              'MWVL',
                              'RR',
                              'DET',
                              'ADL',
                              'LDL',
                              'DIV',
                              'EDL',
                              'LAM',
                              'TT',
                              'LVL',
                              'EVL',
                              'AWVL',
                              'LWVL',
                              'LWVLI',
                              'EWVL',
                              'Ratio_DRR',
                              'Ratio_LD'},
                        orient='row').lazy()

       else:

          new_df = pl.DataFrame(data=data,
                              schema = {
                                  'MDL',
                                  'MVL',
                                  'MWVL',
                                  'RR',
                                  'DET',
                                  'ADL',
                                  'LDL',
                                  'DIV',
                                  'EDL',
                                  'LAM',
                                  'TT',
                                  'LVL',
                                  'EVL',
                                  'AWVL',
                                  'LWVL',
                                  'LWVLI',
                                  'EWVL',
                                  'Ratio_DRR',
                                  'Ratio_LD'
                                  },
                                  orient='row')

          #append new dataframe to results
          result_df = result_df.collect().vstack(new_df, in_place=True).lazy()


return result_df
                

When returning the dataframe outside the function, the column names are no longer in order, but the data is.
e.g
result.schema

OrderedDict([('LAM', Float64),
             ('LDL', Float64),
             ('ADL', Float64),
             ('DIV', Float64),
             ('MDL', Float64),
             ('MWVL', Float64),
             ('LWVL', Float64),
             ('MVL', Float64),
             ('TT', Float64),
             ('DET', Float64),
             ('RR', Float64),
             ('EDL', Float64),
             ('Ratio_LD', Float64),
             ('Ratio_DRR', Float64),
             ('LVL', Float64),
             ('LWVLI', Float64),
             ('EWVL', Float64),
             ('EVL', Float64),
             ('AWVL', Float64)])

I assume this is due to my naivety about how lazyframes work, but is there a way to enfore the order without renaming the columns?
Thanks.

The problem is you're using a set which is an unordered collection in Python.
>>> schema = {'MDL', 'MVL', 'MWVL', 'RR', 'DET'}
>>> type(schema)
set
>>> schema
{'DET', 'MDL', 'MVL', 'MWVL', 'RR'} # "random" order

You want to use a list/tuple instead.
There is a LazyFrame constructor, and you can use concat to combine frames (eager or lazy).

pl.LazyFrame()

pl.concat()


frames = []

for ...:
    df = pl.LazyFrame(...)
    frames.append(df)

return pl.concat(frames)

The use of .vstack() and any in_place methods/parameters in Polars is generally not recommended.

Ahh, so simple, thank you! Thanks for the added tip regarding concat.

You need to be careful about the ordering when creating the dataframe. Here is a modified version of your code:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

def my_func():
    array_list = [np.zeros((1, 19))] * 2  

    columns = [
        'MDL', 'MVL', 'MWVL', 'RR', 'DET', 'ADL', 'LDL', 'DIV', 'EDL', 'LAM',
        'TT', 'LVL', 'EVL', 'AWVL', 'LWVL', 'LWVLI', 'EWVL', 'Ratio_DRR', 'Ratio_LD'
    ]

    for i, _ in enumerate(array_list):
        result = np.zeros((1, 19)).flatten().tolist()

        if i == 0:
            result_df = pl.DataFrame({col: [val] for col, val in zip(columns, result)}).lazy()
        else:
            new_df = pl.DataFrame({col: [val] for col, val in zip(columns, result)})
            result_df = pl.concat([result_df.collect(), new_df]).lazy()

    return result_df

result_df = my_func()
print(result_df.collect())

which returns:
shape: (2, 19)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬───┬───────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ MDL ┆ MVL ┆ MWVL ┆ RR  ┆ … ┆ LWVLI ┆ EWVL ┆ Ratio_DRR ┆ Ratio_LD │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64 ┆   ┆ f64   ┆ f64  ┆ f64       ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪═══╪═══════╪══════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0 ┆ … ┆ 0.0   ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0       ┆ 0.0      │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0 ┆ … ┆ 0.0   ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0       ┆ 0.0      │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴───┴───────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┘

And
result_df.schema


OrderedDict([('MDL', Float64),
             ('MVL', Float64),
             ('MWVL', Float64),
             ('RR', Float64),
             ('DET', Float64),
             ('ADL', Float64),
             ('LDL', Float64),
             ('DIV', Float64),
             ('EDL', Float64),
             ('LAM', Float64),
             ('TT', Float64),
             ('LVL', Float64),
             ('EVL', Float64),
             ('AWVL', Float64),
             ('LWVL', Float64),
             ('LWVLI', Float64),
             ('EWVL', Float64),
             ('Ratio_DRR', Float64),
             ('Ratio_LD', Float64)])

